How can i set this for each NEW row
I'm trying to set up this in Google Sheets, where there's info being added to a spreadsheet and a pdf is created from a template. I copied this code from a YT video:
function createBulkPDFs(){
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow()-1, 24).getValues(); 
  let errors = [];
  data.forEach(row => {
    try{
    createPDF(row[2], row[3], row[4], row[8], row[9], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19],"manny"+row[2], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
    errors.push([""]);
    }catch(err){
      errors.push(["Failed"]);
    }

});
  currentSheet.getRange(2, 26,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).setValues(errors);


}

function createPDF(cliente, cotizacion, atencion, ciudad, fecha, manoDeObra, traslados, materiales, total, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder) {

  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{Cliente}", cliente);
  body.replaceText("{Cotizacion}", cotizacion);
  body.replaceText("{Atencion}", atencion);
  body.replaceText("{Ciudad}", ciudad);
  body.replaceText("{Fecha}", fecha);
  body.replaceText("{ManoDeObra}", manoDeObra);
  body.replaceText("{Traslados}", traslados);
  body.replaceText("{Material}", materiales);
  body.replaceText("{Total}", total);

  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);

}


But this creates a new PDF for every single row everytime a new one is added, creating tons of duplicates, how can i set it up so just the new one is created?
I guess this is the line that is responsible for that but i dont know how to change it
data.forEach(row => { try{ createPDF(row[2], row[3], row[4], row[8], row[9], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19],"manny"+row[2], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder); errors.push([""]); }catch(err){ errors.push(["Failed"]); }

to avoid creating duplicates and only generate PDFs for new rows, you need to keep track of which rows have already been processed. one approach is to add a column to your spreadsheet that marks whether a PDF has already been created for a given row. you can then modify your script to only process rows that have not yet been marked

It depends on how the new rows are added.
The simplest option might be to run the script only for the row with the current cell highlighted. This cell has a bolder border than the other highlighted cells.
The following function returns the active sheet, the row number of the current cell, and the row values. Disclaimer: I have yet to test it.
function getCurrentRow(){
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rowNumber = activeSheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  const [ row ] = activeSheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 24).getValues();
  return [
    activeSheet, 
    rowNumber,
    row
  ];
}

The function is to create a PDF for the row having the current cell.
function createPDFforCurrentRow(){
  // from the original code
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("ID");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  let result;
  // New codelines
  const [activeSheet, rowNumber, row] = getCurrentRow();
  // Adapted from the original code 
  try {
    createPDF(row[2], row[3], row[4], row[8], row[9], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19],"manny"+row[2], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);
    result = 'Success';
  } catch(error) {
    result = 'Failure';
  }
  activeSheet.getRange(rowNumber, 26).setValue(result);
}

Among the other options, you might use a trigger. Google Apps Script has two trigger categories: simple and installable. If the rows are inserted by a Google Forms submission, you might use one of the form submit triggers. The most convenient might be the corresponding spreadsheet rather than the one corresponding to a form.

You could check if the file already exists, by using DriveApp.getFileById('file_name').
Then, call your createPDF function if the result is false.
